# python regex find values with newline character also

Tags: python, regex

I am working on this regex problem I'm unable to solve. The regex I've made

```
import re
message = """[key    X] value
[key    X]  value value
[key    X]  value
value
value
value
[key     ] value
[key     ] ?
[key     ] ?"""

messageRegex = re.compile(r"\[(.*?)][\s](.*)")

for value in messageRegex.findall(message):
    print(value)
```

The output to this is, as given below and not everything is getting captured.

```
('key    X', 'value') ('key\tX', 'value value') ('key\tX', 'value')
('key\t ', 'value') ('key\t ', '?') ('key\t ', '?')
```

[image]

I would expect the output to look like

```
('key    X', 'value') ('key\tX', 'value value') ('key\tX', 'value \nvalue \nvalue \nvalue')
('key\t ', 'value') ('key\t ', '?') ('key\t ', '?')
```

Comment: Anchor at the start and make the first two patterns optional - `^(?:\[(.*?)]\s+)?(.*)`, see https://regex101.com/r/h3wwUa/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the response. I may not have explained it correctly - From the link you've provided  I'm looking for the 'value' in line 4,5,6 to be a part of match 3

Comment: You should have explained it in the question, please edit it. Is `message` a single string variable?

Comment: Yes, the message is a single string.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'^\[([^][]*)]\s+(.*(?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*)', message, re.M)`

Comment: One last one, how about removing the X at the end?

Comment: Try `re.compile(r"^\[([^][]*?)X?]\s+(.*(?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*)", re.M)`, see [Python demo](https://ideone.com/y034Oz) and  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fySzoJ/2). Just move it out of the first group and add `?` after it to make it optional, make Group 1 pattern lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^\[([^][]*)]\s+(.*(?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fySzoJ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\[` - `[`
- `([^][]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*(?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*` - zero or more repetitions of:

    - `\n(?!\[[^][]*])` - a newline not followed with a `[...]` substring
    - `.*` - the rest of the line

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/tOjYQK):

```
import re
message = """[key    X] value
[key    X]  value value
[key    X]  value
value
value
value
[key     ] value
[key     ] ?
[key     ] ?"""

messageRegex = re.compile(r"^\[([^][]*)]\s+(.*(?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*)", re.M)

for value in messageRegex.findall(message):
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
('key    X', 'value')
('key    X', 'value value')
('key    X', 'value\nvalue\nvalue\nvalue')
('key     ', 'value')
('key     ', '?')
('key     ', '?')
```